# Cast a 10 bit unsigned integer to a signed integer in python

Tags: python, int, uint

I have a list of numbers in the range 0-1023. I would like to convert them to integers such that 1023 maps to -1, 1022 maps to -2 etc.. while 0, 1, 2, ....511 remain unchanged.

I came up with a simple:

```
def convert(x):
    return (x - 2**9) % 2**10 - 2**9
```

is there a better way?

Comment: In some programming languages, the `%` operator yields a negative (or zero) value for a negative left operand, so the code could perhaps be made clearer by changing `(x - 2**9)` to `(x + 2**9)`. Aside from that, this seems like a reasonable implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naivest possible solution:

```
def convert(x):
    if x >= 512:
        x -= 1024
    return x
```

Comment: Alternatively, reducing three lines to one:  `return x if x < 512 else x - 1024`

Comment: or `return x - 1024 * (x >= 512)`

Comment: @rmartinjak, multiplying by a boolean requires Python to do an extra cast, and as a result that solution is a bit slower than the other ones. Your original solution and John1024's seem to be roughly equivalent. I haven't done any rigorous testing yet, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
def convert(x):
    return x - (x >> 9) * 1024
```

Using [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

```
from ctypes import c_short

def convert(x):
    return c_short(x << 6).value >> 6
```

Comment: perfect answer, I may add some explanations

Answer (score 0):

```
 max_uint_value = 512

 def unassigned_to_int(uint):
      return uint - max_uint_value if uint >= max_uint_value else uint
```